# Python script receiving input from .txt file issue

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a little script that reads pc names off an external .txt file and then runs a command against each of them.

My code:

```
import subprocess

listCommand = ("c:\delprof2\DelProf2.exe /l /c:")

userID = raw_input("Please enter the name of the ID to remove: ")

with open (r"pc-list.txt") as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        subprocess.Popen(listCommand + line + " /id:" + userID).wait()
        raw_input("Press return to continue...")
```

The contents of the .txt file:

```
itroom01
itroom02
itroom03
itroom04
itroom05
```

When I come to run the script, it doesn't seem to like the input from the file. It's like it doesn't know where the end of the line is correctly. Is there anything that anyone can see that looks wrong? Maybe I need to format the txt file differently..?

Any thoughts would be appreciated,

Chris.

(Python 2.7)

Comment: what is the full text of the error you're getting, if any?

Comment: Bear in mind that the `line` will end with a newline `'\n'` - you may want to `str.strip` it.

Comment: @MattDMo, If I change the txt file for one specific PC, it reports: "Listing inactive profiles on 'itroom01'.", whereas if it runs with the txt file, it reports: "Listing inactive profiles on 'itroom01", with the final "'." on the next line. And then subsequently cannot find the PC on the network.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: How would I add that to the script? Thanks.

Comment: @user3514446 [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)